# CURL error: The requested URL returned error: 403

Tags: php, curl, http-status-code-403

I am attempting to retrieve offers for a specific product from an online shop using cURL, however, I am consistently receiving a 403 error.

```php
        $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://kaspi.kz/yml/offer-view/offers/100409201');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"cityId":"750000000","id":"100409201","merchantUID":"","limit":5,"page":0,"sort":true,"product":{"brand":"IKEA","categoryCodes":["Kitchen storage containers","Food storage containers","Kitchenware","Home","Categories"],"baseProductCodes":[],"groups":[]},"zoneId":"Magnum_ZONE1","installationId":"-1"}');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Accept: application/json, text/*';
    $headers[] = 'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6';
    $headers[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';
    $headers[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
        $headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        die(json_encode([
            'status' => 0,
            'text' => curl_error($ch)
        ]));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
```

Additionally, I attempted to replicate the cURL command by copying it from the browser and converting it from bash to PHP, however, this method did not yield any results.

This is URL of product what I need: https://kaspi.kz/shop/p/ikea-banka-raitan-30372471-steklo-100409201/?c=750000000#!/item
After loading page they run this https://kaspi.kz/yml/offer-view/offers/100409201 URL with POST

Comment: Opening that URL in a browser will also yield a `403 Forbidden`. Have you successfully opened that URL in bash? What command did you use?

Comment: @brombeer This is URL of product: https://kaspi.kz/shop/p/ikea-banka-raitan-30372471-steklo-100409201/?c=750000000#!/item
From there I took that URL where I get offers

Comment: The XHR request on that site also sends cookies, you will probably have to do the same. And some other request headers might need to match as well.

Comment: @CBroe yes. I've tried with all of headers. I copy curl from browser and converted to php. But result is the same

Comment: Maybe they have tied this to the requesting IP address or something. Then you can copy headers and cookie values out of your browser all day long, won't help if the can determine that these "belong" to a different IP, than the one that made the original request. You should make a request from your server to the product page URL first, and then send whatever cookies you receive there, with your second request.

Comment: @CBroe Logically. I'm going to try now. Thanks

Comment: @CBroe now I get 429 error. Can you try? Link this: https://kaspi.kz/shop/p/ikea-banka-raitan-30372471-steklo-100409201/?c=750000000